# Determine if Windows Phone 8.1 app is running in the emulator?

Tags: emulation, windows-phone-8.1

In an 8.1 Universal app, is there an equivalent to:

```
if (Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType == DeviceType.Emulator)
{
  // Emulator-specific code
}
```

I've looked and can't find a similar API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation deviceInfo = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();
```

`deviceInfo` should give you info about `SystemManufacturer` ("Microsoft") & `SystemProductName` ("Virtual").

EDIT: I wrote a [blog post](http://igrali.com/2014/07/17/get-device-information-windows-phone-8-1-winrt/) about this problem.

Comment: The blog in not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
if (Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.IsDevelopmentMode)
{
  // Emulator-specific code
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.isdevelopmentmode.aspx